# What is the default environment for Plumber in Docker?

Tags: r, docker, plumber

I ran into an issue where I run the following at the top of my entrypoints.R file:
`load("some_file.Rdata")` but the objects never seem to load. I made this endpoint to check for what is loaded and it comes back empty:

```
#* @serializer text
#* @get /objects
check_objects <- function(){
  capture.output(ls())
  
}
```

However, after some trial and error, when I save the objects as rds files and use the double-assignment operator, I now have access to them:

`file <<- readRDS("some_file.Rds")`

How do I determine which environment is being used so I can `load()` properly?

Comment: Did you check out this part of the documentation? https://www.rplumber.io/articles/execution-model.html

Comment: It says "When you plumb() a file, Plumber calls source() on that file which will evaluate any top-level code that you have defined.". I assume that means `load()` is evaluated but clearly that is not the case, because the data is not available. Examples like this (https://mlr-org.com/gallery/technical/2020-08-13-a-production-example-using-plumber-and-docker/), which is similar to my Docker/Plumber set up, also show it should work but does not seem to. Is the recommendation to explicitly create an environment in plumb()?

Comment: The solution was: `load(my_file.Rdata, envir = .GlobalEnv)`. I guess I assumed it was loading to the global env, but it was not.